# How to catch a System.TimeoutException if it's thrown by an unknown thread in external code?

Tags: c#, exception

I have a 3rd party GSM communication assembly (no source) linked to my main application. Such assembly has a "received sms event". If I add an handler to it, the assembly starts a thread which throws, occasionally, a System.TimeoutException (caused by a read timeout from COM port).

Since I have no control on external code and I need my application not to crash in such scenario, how could I catch or, better, tell the assembly to ignore a specific type of exception?

Thank you in advance,
F.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the current AppDomain unhandled exception

Nice article: AppDomain.UnhandledException [Part 1](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/appdomainunhandledexception-part-1.aspx) [Part 2](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/AppDomainUnhandledException-Part-2.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Fabske, I assume it's not possible to prevent application from shutting down, e.g. ignoring the specific exception, is it?

Comment: I don't think so. But you can try to load the 3rd party code in a new AppDomain and I think in this design it'll not exit the application, but zfter the exception you'll need to unload the second AppDomain and recreate one to rerun the 3rd party soft again